# SAS: Search for multiple keywords and terms in multiple SAS programs in drive or folder

Tags: loops, syntax, macros, sas, pipe

I'm trying to search for multiple keywords in multiple SAS programs in a specified drive (below is H: and I'd also like to eventually put this in a macro). Unfortunately it's impossible for me to create test files, but my example searches for the terms `print`,`freq`, and `means` on the `H:` drive. I create an empty dataset `search_results` that will be built throughout the loop.

Search for individual terms works fine, but looping over multiple terms yields 0 observations yet no errors.

```
** INDIVIDUAL TERM SEARCH WORKS **;


filename search pipe 'for /r H: %i in (*.sas) do @findstr /i /m "print" "%i"';
data search_results;
  infile search length =_len;
  input @1 filepath $varying512. _len;
run;


** MACRO LOOP DOES NOT WORK **;


%let search_vars=print freq means;

/* create dataset to append results */
data search_results;
    length filepath $512.;
    filepath = "";
run;

%macro loop_through(search_vars);
    %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&search_vars.));
    %do i=1 %to &n.;
        %let var=%scan(&search_vars.,&i.);
            filename search pipe 'for /r h: %i in (*.sas) do @findstr /i /m "&var." "%i"';
                data temp;
                infile search length =_len;
                input @1 filepath $varying512. _len;
            run;

            /* append results */
            data search_results;
                if 0 then modify search_results;
                set temp open=defer;
                output;
            run;
    %end;
%mend;

%loop_through(&search_vars.);
```

I assume it's something with in the `pipe` syntax (maybe quote issues?) but I am not at all familiar with it. My other guess is that it is searching for the terms in consecutive order `print means freq` instead of an actual loop. Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you suppressed the macro variable expansion by using single quotes to quote your command.

You can write a much simpler program without the macro code.

```
data search_results ;
  input var $32. ;
  length cmd $200 ;
  cmd = catx(' ','for /r h: %i in (*.sas) do @findstr /i /m',quote(trim(var)),'"%i"');
  infile search pipe filevar=cmd lrecl=512 truncover end=eof ;
  do while (not eof);
    input filepath $char512. ;
    output;
  end;
cards;
print
freq
means
;
```

If you want to pass in the list of terms to search for in a macro variable instead of a data file then just use a DO loop to iterate over the list of terms.

```
data search_results ;
  length var $32 cmd $200 ;
  do i=1 to countw("&search_terms");
    var=scan("&search_terms",i);
    cmd = catx(' ','for /r h: %i in (*.sas) do @findstr /i /m',quote(trim(var)),'"%i"');
    infile search pipe filevar=cmd lrecl=512 truncover end=eof ;
    do while (not eof);
      input filepath $char512. ;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: nice use of embedded pipe!

Comment: This is nice; however, the variables in the `cards` statement are dynamically put into a macro since they will change periodically. I know you can use something like `textResolved=dequote(resolve(quote(var)));` to use macro variables in the `cards` statement but it doesn't work in this syntax. Is there a way to put the terms in a macro variable and use that in the `cards` statement?

Comment: If you don't want to read the list from a file just change the outer loop. `do i=1 to countw("&search_vars"); var=scan("&search_vars",i);...end; stop;`

Comment: Doesn't your method remove the outer loop though? I'm sorry I guess I'm confused since my original method had an outer loop.

Comment: Remove the outer loop of the INPUT statement and replace with the DO loop.

Comment: ERROR: INPUT statement executed before INFILE statement.

I'm not doing something right. I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: @Tom -- thanks for all the help. My results are picking out terms that contain the keyword and not the exact match, i.e. the term `freq` pulls the keyword `frequency`. I tried combinations of `/l /s /i /m` but can't seem to get it right -- do you know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

It was likely due to the fact that SAS macro variables do not resolve inside single quotes (`'`).

Try:

```
%let search_vars=print freq means;

/* create dataset to append results */
data search_results;
    length filepath $512.;
    filepath = "";
run;

%macro loop_through(search_vars);
    %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&search_vars.));
    %do i=1 %to &n.;
        %let var=%scan(&search_vars.,&i.);
            /* modified here */
            filename search pipe "for /r h: %i in (*.sas) do @findstr /i /m ""&var."" ""%i"" ";
                data temp;
                infile search length =_len;
                input @1 filepath $varying512. _len;
            run;

            /* append results */
            data search_results;
                if 0 then modify search_results;
                set temp open=defer;
                output;
            run;
    %end;
%mend;

%loop_through(&search_vars.);
```